# Bootstrap Treeview - find node by property value

Tags: jstree, bootstrap-treeview

I'm using Bootstrap Treeview to display hierarchical date. The node data is retrieved using a call to a Web API endpoint and the data includes other name/value pairs, including a unique ID number, which are added as node properties.

I would like to select a node, given that unique ID number, but this doesn't look possible.

The **selectNode** method accepts either a node object or the **nodeId** that is automatically assigned to the node (not sure how to use this as it's not possible to predict or discover what this is!).

There is a **search** method, but this only seems to search the **text** property of the nodes.

Ideally, I'm looking for something like a lambda expression in the search method that can specify the property to be searched, e.g.

```
var node = $('#tree').treeview('search', [n => n.MyProperty == '123345']);
```

Is this at all possible? Is there another way to achieve this?

I've done a lot of work to get things working and this is the final hurdle. Would I be better switching to jsTree?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to use jsTree. Worked perfectly!